# Codeigniter Active Record - Delete where not in array

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have found this codeigniter active record query where I can delete items in an array

```
$this->db->delete('stack', array('id' => $id))
```

However, I would like to delete items which are not in the array.

Is this possible.?

Comment: I don't have a chance to test it, but would that not work:
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $ids);
$this->db->delete('stack');

Comment: Perfect... add it as an answer and i'll give you the tick!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $ids);
$this->db->delete('stack');
```